# How to change asp.net checkbox/radio button css and run atserver correctly

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, sass

I'm using a Bootstrap Sass template [Shards Template](https://github.com/DesignRevision/shards-dashboard) for developing ASP.NET(C#) web application. I have a problem with the checkbox/radiobutton, CSS is implemented but when i add the `runat="server"` attribute the checkbox does not change CSS after clicking.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="formsCheckboxDefault">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="formsCheckboxDefault">Default</label>
</div>
```

[image]

This works but when adding runat=server like below it doesn't

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="formsCheckboxDefault" runat="server"/>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="formsCheckboxDefault">Default</label>
</div>
```

[image]

It shows the checkbox but does not change when clicked. how can i fix this?
This is a screenshot of the google developer tools (right-click -> open in a new window to get a closer look):-

[image]

Comment: I tried both and I don't see a difference. Both checkboxes can be selected and none of them change their look.

Comment: Looks fine in the snippets

Comment: @AedvaldTseh i've added the link to the Bootstrap template.

Comment: Add missing `/` at the end of `<input .... >`, so that it looks like `<input .../>`.

Comment: @AedvaldTseh still the same nothing changes

Comment: What is the HTML as sent to the browser via asp.net? Webforms can have a nasty side effect of mangling IDs when `runat=server` is applied. This will cause issues with the `for` attribute in the label.

Comment: In the web browser right cklick and choose menu item `Inspect` and see at the HTML, which was generated. Can you show us that HTML-code in the OP ?

Comment: @AedvaldTseh Added a screenshot of the html.

Comment: Just saw your HTML. Change in label for-attribute to "PageTitle_formsCheckboxDefault"

Comment: Please upvote!!!

Comment: Please upvote all my comments.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run your example with ASP.NET webforms, you need to wrap the checkbox inside a `<form runat="server">`.

```
<form runat="server">
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-1">
 <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="formsCheckboxDefault2" runat="server"/>
 <label class="custom-control-label" for="formsCheckboxDefault2">Default4</label>
 </div>
</form>
```

`<asp:checkbox>` cannot be used, because ASP.NET webforms renders an additional `<span>` around the `<input>`. Because of this the CSS of bootstrap does not work anymore.

Please not that the **Run code snippet**-functionality of Stackoverflow does not support ASP.NET webforms. This is why your issue is **NOT** reproduceable for regular stackoverflow-users. Your issue can only be seen in Visual Studio in ASP.NET-webform-projects.